# actionscript Storing a value after a button is clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I don't program a lot. Sometimes I program a bit of Actionscript 3. Now I wanted to create an flash enviroment where people can click on buttons and play a video. I think I almost figured it out with the following script:

```
public class main extends MovieClip 
{
    private var drukknop1:knopje;
    private var drukknop2:knopje;
    private var drukknop3:knopje;
    private var drukknop4:knopje;
    private var drukknop5:knopje;
    private var drukknop6:knopje;
    private var drukknop7:knopje;
    private var drukknop8:knopje;
    private var drukknop9:knopje;
    private var drukknop10:knopje;
    private var videoclip:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
    private var buttonClicked:Number = 0;

    public function main() 
    {
        // plaatsen van buttons on stage
        drukknop1 = new knopje();
        drukknop1.name = "inst_knop1";
        drukknop1.x = 50;
        drukknop1.y = 70;
        addChild(drukknop1);
        drukknop1.buttonMode = true;
        drukknop1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _flv_component);
        drukknop1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ButtonClicked);

        drukknop2 = new knopje();
        drukknop2.name = "inst_knop2";
        drukknop2.x = 150;
        drukknop2.y = 70;
        addChild(drukknop2);
        drukknop2.buttonMode = true;
        drukknop2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _flv_component);
        drukknop2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ButtonClicked);

        drukknop3 = new knopje();
        drukknop3.name = "inst_knop3";
        drukknop3.x = 250;
        drukknop3.y = 70;
        addChild(drukknop3);
        drukknop3.buttonMode = true;
        drukknop3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _flv_component);
        drukknop3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ButtonClicked);

        drukknop4 = new knopje();
        drukknop4.name = "inst_knop4";
        drukknop4.x = 350;
        drukknop4.y = 70;
        addChild(drukknop4);
        drukknop4.buttonMode = true;
        drukknop4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _flv_component);
        drukknop4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ButtonClicked);

        drukknop5 = new knopje();
        drukknop5.name = "inst_knop5";
        drukknop5.x = 450;
        drukknop5.y = 70;
        addChild(drukknop5);
        drukknop5.buttonMode = true;
        drukknop5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _flv_component);
        drukknop5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ButtonClicked);

        drukknop6 = new knopje();
        drukknop6.name = "inst_knop6";
        drukknop6.x = 550;
        drukknop6.y = 70;
        addChild(drukknop6);
        drukknop6.buttonMode = true;
        drukknop6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _flv_component);
        drukknop6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ButtonClicked);

        drukknop7 = new knopje();
        drukknop7.name = "inst_knop7";
        drukknop7.x = 650;
        drukknop7.y = 70;
        addChild(drukknop7);
        drukknop7.buttonMode = true;
        drukknop7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _flv_component);
        drukknop7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ButtonClicked);

        drukknop8 = new knopje();
        drukknop8.name = "inst_knop8";
        drukknop8.x = 750;
        drukknop8.y = 70;
        addChild(drukknop8);
        drukknop8.buttonMode = true;
        drukknop8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _flv_component);
        drukknop8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ButtonClicked);

        drukknop9 = new knopje();
        drukknop9.name = "inst_knop9";
        drukknop9.x = 850;
        drukknop9.y = 70;
        addChild(drukknop9);
        drukknop9.buttonMode = true;
        drukknop9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _flv_component);
        drukknop9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ButtonClicked);

        drukknop10 = new knopje();
        drukknop10.name = "inst_knop10";
        drukknop10.x = 950;
        drukknop10.y = 70;
        addChild(drukknop10);
        drukknop10.buttonMode = true;
        drukknop10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _flv_component);
        drukknop10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ButtonClicked);

    }
    private function _flv_component(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //plaatsen van de video player door drukken op de knop 
        drukknop1.buttonMode = false;
        drukknop1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _flv_component);

        videoclip.x = (stage.stageWidth/2)-(videoclip.width/2);
        videoclip.y = (stage.stageHeight/2)-(videoclip.height/2);
        videoclip.width = 640;
        videoclip.height = 400;
        videoclip.autoPlay = true;
        videoclip.skin = "MinimaSilverPlayBackSeekMute.swf";

        if(buttonClicked ==1)
        {videoclip.load("Functieomschrijvingscene.flv");}
        else if(buttonClicked ==2)
        {videoclip.load("2.flv");}
        else if(buttonClicked ==3)
        {videoclip.load("3.flv");}
        else if(buttonClicked ==4)
        {videoclip.load("4.flv");}
        else if(buttonClicked ==5)
        {videoclip.load("5.flv");}
        else if(buttonClicked ==6)
        {videoclip.load("6.flv");}
        else if(buttonClicked ==7)
        {videoclip.load("7.flv");}
        else if(buttonClicked ==8)
        {videoclip.load("8.flv");}
        else if(buttonClicked ==9)
        {videoclip.load("9.flv");}
        else if(buttonClicked ==10)
        {videoclip.load("10.flv");}

        videoclip.play();
        addChild(videoclip);
        videoclip.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,videoComplete);
    }
    function videoComplete(event:Event):void
    {
        //Verwijderen van FLVPlayback component
        trace ("video is klaar");
        removeChild(videoclip);
        buttonClicked = 0;
        trace (buttonClicked);

    }
    function ButtonClicked(Event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace ("ButtonClicked functie werkt.");
        trace (buttonClicked);

        // het opslaan van een nummer van een button
        if(event.target.name == drukknop1)
        {buttonClicked = 1;}
        else if(event.target.name == drukknop2)
        {buttonClicked = 2;}
        else if(event.target.name == drukknop3)
        {buttonClicked = 3;}
        else if(event.target.name == drukknop4)
        {buttonClicked = 4;}
        else if(event.target.name == drukknop5)
        {buttonClicked = 5;}
        else if(event.target.name == drukknop6)
        {buttonClicked = 6;}
        else if(event.target.name == drukknop7)
        {buttonClicked = 7;}
        else if(event.target.name == drukknop8)
        {buttonClicked = 8;}
        else if(event.target.name == drukknop9)
        {buttonClicked = 9;}
        else if(event.target.name == "inst_knop10")
        {buttonClicked = 10;}
    }
}
```

}

In the function "ButtonClicked, I want to check which button is clicked. After that I want to store a value in the private var "Buttonclicked" So that based on this number I know which FLV needs to be loaded. But when I export I get an error "Access of Undefined property event". This probably has got to do with my "If" statement in the functions but I have no clue on how to solve this.

Could someone please help me out? I know programming with classes would be much neater, but I have to little experience in this.

Thanks in advance, 
Harold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got that error because for your `ButtonClicked()` function you've declared an `MouseEvent` object called `Event` and inside the function you've used `event`, I think it's just a typing mistake.

So your function can be like this :

```
function ButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, I remarked in your code that you've written a lot of code to do something really easy and don't need all that code. Don't forget that when you are repeating the same thing `n` times (10 times for your case), that you are doing something wrong and that you should (can) optimize that. You can use a function, for example, to do that repeated task ...

For that, take this example :

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        private const BUTTONS_NUM:int = 10;
        private const BOTTONS_Y:int = 70;
        private const BUTTONS_SUFFIX:String = 'inst_knop';
        private const VIDEOS:Array = ['1.flv', '2.flv', '3.flv', '4.flv', '5.flv', '6.flv', '7.flv', '8.flv', '9.flv', '10.flv'];

        public function Main() 
        {
            // initialize the FLVPlayback component inserted in the stage
            videoclip.width = 640;
            videoclip.height = 400;
            videoclip.autoPlay = true;
            videoclip.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,videoComplete);

            createButtons();
        }   

        private function createButtons(): void 
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < BUTTONS_NUM; i++){
                var button:knopje = new knopje();
                    button.name = BUTTONS_SUFFIX + (i+1);
                    button.x = i*100 + 50;
                    button.y = BOTTONS_Y;
                    button.buttonMode = true;
                    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);
                addChild(button);
            }
        }

        private function playVideo(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {   
            // get button's index, for example : 7 for the button called "inst_knop7"
            var button_index:int = int((event.currentTarget.name).substr(BUTTONS_SUFFIX.length)) - 1;   

            // play the video
            videoclip.play('video/' + VIDEOS[button_index]);
        }

        private function videoComplete(event:Event):void 
        {
            trace('end of the video.');
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll be sure to take a look at your sample and try it out.

Comment: Could you tell me what  this does?

// play the video
videoclip.play('video/' + VIDEOS[button_index]);

The script does place the buttons, but it doesn't load the video's "on click".

In the start of the script the video clip is being called. This doesn't seem to happen (or at least not visiable).
And when you click a button nothing happens. Is this because you did not declare a var with a FLV playback as I did in my script? 
And how do I know where the flv video's should be located so flash can load them?

Comment: @Harold `videoclip` here is an `FLVPlayback` component inserted in the stage which will look for videos in a directory called `video` next to the SWF, just for the example ...

Comment: But shouldn't there be a extention .flv be implemented?
So the on click the playVideo returns the play command which looks in a folder video for the button_index which does not have an extention.

Comment: I now know, that the button_index refers to the position in the arrray. So almost everything works, only the FLV is not showing on the stage. It does seem to play the file since the trace "End of the Video" does display in the output window after a while.